# Hi, i need filter data from 4 table which stored as comma separated in table

Tags: laravel, mysqli, laravel-5

[image]

Hi, As per image i have 3 table, 1. visits table in this table village_id value find in route_list villagemaster_id and if it available select doctors_id and using this doctors_id i need that all doctors name from user table using doctors id please give me solution.

Comment: Have you tried using a controller?

Comment: It is because `+` in angular expression means `concatenation`. So it does the string concatenation.

Comment: It seems clear that your values are being interpreted as strings then concatenated. You could try changing your expression to 0 + a + b to force numeric conversion

Comment: Change the `type="number"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use directive for it (It uses parseInt):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('castToInteger', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                return parseInt(value, 10);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-init="a=2;b=5">
<input type="text" cast-to-integer="true" name="a" ng-model="a" />
<input type="text" cast-to-integer="true" name="b" ng-model="b" />

<p>Total in dollar: {{ a + b }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to number! It may help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="a=2;b=5">
<input type="number" name="a" ng-model="a" />
<input type="number" name="b" ng-model="b" />
    
<p>Total in dollar: {{ a + b }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```